# Cannot run the macro Listbox4_Change. The macro May not be available in this workbook or all macros disabled

Tags: excel, vba, dashboard

Can anyone please  help me with excel issue. I have created a dynamic dashboard in excel using sumifs on data layer and index match functions on presentation layer. I have placed a simple List box form control with no VBA or macro.

My dashboard was working fine, without any issue, but on final step I was just trying to make the List box control float on the sheet with scrolling.

I found a vba code, I opened vba from developer mode, pasted code, but that deleted same.

Since then upon any selection of List box item, it is giving me error “ Cannot run the macro Listbox4_Change. The macro May not be available in this workbook or all macros disabled.”

I have tried pretty much every thing I found on google. Created a macro and deleted, copied one line code in all sheets of vba and deleted, enabled Macro security setting, but nothing really is working .

I am stuck badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've added a macro and then removed it, but haven't removed the macro assignment on the list box.

Right-click on the control and choose Assign Macro, delete the Macro name, and hit OK.

Comment: yes, that's what happened. already did the same and issue resolved. You Got it absolutely right. Thanks.